# Gravar na Sessão cordeadas de um Link e destruir outra sessão para fazer tradução de site

Tags: php, session

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como Posso fazer que ao clicar em alguma bandeirinha ela grave em uma sessão os dados referentes a a sua linguagem

- Brasil         ==> grava na sessão a string  "br"
- Estados Unidos ==> grava na sessão a string  "usa"

e ao clicar em uma destruir a outra

```
Estou indo por esse principio mais não sei se é o correto
lng = $_REQUEST['lng'];
$_SESSION['lng'] = $lng; 


<a href="<?echo $nome_do_arquivo?>?lng=br"><img src="img/br.jpg" width="28" 
height="16" alt="Image" data-retina="true"/></a>

<a href="<?echo $nome_do_arquivo?>?lng=usa"><img src="img/lang_en.png" 
width="28" height="16" alt="Image" data-retina="true"/></a>

<a href="<?echo $nome_do_arquivo?>?lng=fran"><img src="img/lang_fr.png"  
width="28" height="16" alt="Image" data-retina="true"/></a>

<a href="<?echo $nome_do_arquivo?>?lng=spain"><img src="img/lang_es.png" 
width="28" height="16" alt="Image" data-retina="true"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ser feito com um request `POST` ou `GET` (`POST` fica mais agradável para o cliente) simples. Depois de receber o request basta guardar na `SESSION` do utilizador ou até na DB (caso o utilizador estiver logado). Não irei demonstrar o código pois é uma coisa bastante simples e você deveria conseguir fazer a implementação.